KivyMD Google like suggestions while typing
I'm new to kivy(MD).
On one screen I have a TextInput where I can type city names. When I click on the "next" button, the screen is switched and the city name variable is passed to that screen.
What I would like to have is that while typing, there are suggestions showing with city names starting with the typed text. Just like one is googling something.
How can I acchieve this?
Thanks in advance!

This is not a service for writing code, but for helping with problems you have with your written code. Having said that,  you could extend TextInput and possibly Spinner to do what you want.
